# Two-body orbit modelling problems

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector, orbital-mechanics

**Skip to Update 2 below, if you don't want to read too much background.**

I'm trying to implement a model for simple orbital simulations (two body).

However, when I try to use the code I've written, the plots generated from the result look quite odd.

The program uses initial state vectors (position and velocity) to calculate the Keplerian orbital elements, which are used to then calculate the next position, and returned as the next two state vectors.

This seems to work fine, and by itself, plots correctly as long as I keep the plot on the orbital plane. But I would like to rotate the plot to the frame of reference (the parent body) so that I can see a cool 3D view of what the orbits look like (obvs).

Right now, I suspect that the bug is in how I convert from the two state vectors in the orbital plane, to rotating them to the frame of reference. I am using the equations from step 6 of [this document](https://downloads.rene-schwarz.com/download/M001-Keplerian_Orbit_Elements_to_Cartesian_State_Vectors.pdf) to create the following code from (but applying individual roation matricies [[copied from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations)]):

```
from numpy import sin, cos, matrix, newaxis, asarray, squeeze, dot

def Rx(theta):
    """
    Return a rotation matrix for the X axis and angle *theta*
    """
    return matrix([
        [1, 0,           0           ],
        [0, cos(theta), -sin(theta)  ],
        [0, sin(theta), cos(theta)   ],
    ], dtype="float64")

def Rz(theta):
    """
    Return a rotation matrix for the Z axis and angle *theta*
    """
    return matrix([
        [cos(theta), -sin(theta),   0],
        [sin(theta), cos(theta),    0],
        [0,          0,             1],
    ], dtype="float64")

def rotate1(vector, O, i, w):
    # The starting value of *vector* is just a 1-dimensional numpy
    # array.
    # Transform into a column vector.
    vector = vector[:, newaxis]
    # Perform the rotation
    R = Rz(-O) * Rx(-i) * Rz(-w)
    res2 = dot(R, vector)
    # Transform back into a row vector (because that's what
    # the rest of the program uses)
    return squeeze(asarray(res2))
```

(For context, [this is the full class](https://gist.github.com/petronius/066f2731d00292eac0ed) I am using for the orbit model.)

When I plot X and Y coordinates from the result, I get this:

[image]

But when I change the rotation matrix to `R = Rz(-O) * Rx(-i)`, I get this more plausible plot (although obviously missing one rotation, and slightly off-center):

[image]

And when I reduce it further to `R = Rx(-i)`, as one would expect, I get this:

[image]

So as I said, I am fairly sure that it is not the orbital calculation code that is behaving weirdly, but rather some error in the rotation code. But I'm not sure where to narrow this down, as I'm pretty new to both numpy and matrix math in general.

---

**Update**: Based on [stochastic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34435493/1583183) I transposed the matricies (`R = Rz(-O).T * Rx(-i).T * Rz(-w).T`), but then got this plot:

[image]

which made me wonder if my conversion to screen coordinates was somehow wrong -- but it looks correct to me (and is the same code as the more-correct plots with less rotation) namely:

```
def recenter(v_position, viewport_width, viewport_height):
    x, y, z = v_position
    # the size of the viewport in meters
    bounds = 20000000
    # viewport_width is the screen pixels (800)
    scale = viewport_width/bounds
    # Perform the scaling operation
    x *= scale
    y *= scale
    # recenter to screen X and Y measured from the top-left corner
    # of the viewport
    x += viewport_width/2
    y = viewport_height/2 - y
    # Cast to int, because we don't care about pixel fractions
    return int(x), int(y)
```

---

**Update 2**

Although I have triple-checked my implementation of the equations, as well as the rotations with stochastic's help, I still can't get the orbits to come out right. They still appear basically the same as in the plots above.

Using data from the NASA Horizon's system, I set up an orbit with specific state vectors from the ISS (2457380.183935185 = A.D. 2015-Dec-23 16:24:52.0000 (TDB)), and checked them against the Kepler orbit elements for the same moment in time, which produces this result:

```
inclination :
  0.900246137041
  0.900246137041
true_anomaly :
  0.11497063007
  0.0982485984565
long_of_asc_node :
  3.80727461492
  3.80727461492
eccentricity :
  0.000429082122137
  0.000501850615905
semi_major_axis :
  6778560.7037
  6779057.01374
mean_anomaly :
  0.114872215066
  0.0981501816537
argument_of_periapsis :
  0.843226618347
  0.85994864996
```

The top values are my (calculated) values, and the bottom values are the NASA ones. Obviously some floating point precision error is to be expected, but the variations in `mean_anomaly` and `true_anomaly` did strike me as larger than I expected. (I'm currently running all of my numpy calculations using `float128` numbers on a 64-bit system).

In addition, the resulting orbit still looks like the (quite) eccentric first plot, above (even though I know that this LEO ISS orbit is quite circular). So I'm a bit stumped as to what the source of the problem could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have at least two problems.

After looking more closely at the orbital simulation you are doing (see [this additional document](https://downloads.rene-schwarz.com/download/M002-Cartesian_State_Vectors_to_Keplerian_Orbit_Elements.pdf) from the comments), I think the main problem is the initially-very-reasonable-but-yet-untrue assumption that the final plot should look like an ellipse.  In general it will not, since an orbiting body will not necessarily stay in a single plane.

The other problem, I think, is that your rotation matrices are the transpose of what they should be, per the document you described (see below).

**On transposed rotation matrices**

The document you cited does not directly specify whether R_x and R_z should be right-handed rotations of the axes or of the vector they will multiply, though you can figure it out from equation 9 (or 10).  It turns out that they should be right-handed rotations of the axes, not the vector.  That means that they should be defined like this:

```
    return matrix([
        [1, 0,           0           ],
        [0, cos(theta), sin(theta)  ],
        [0,-sin(theta), cos(theta)   ],
    ], dtype="float64")
```

instead of like this:

```
    return matrix([
        [1, 0,           0           ],
        [0, cos(theta),-sin(theta)  ],
        [0, sin(theta), cos(theta)   ],
    ], dtype="float64")
```

I found this out by reproducing equation 9 by hand on paper.

- In that equation, look at the first component of the vector **r**(t).
- There are two terms: one with o_x in it and one with o_y.
- Look at the thing multliplying o_y.  It is:  `-(sin(omega)*cos(Omega)+cos(omega)*cos(i)*sin(Omega))`.
- That leading minus sign is the key. It comes from the minus sign in the first row of your Rz matrix.
- Since the Omega, i, and omega in equation 9 are all negated, that means that the minus sign needs to be on the second row of R_z, which would mean that R_z represents a right-handed rotation of the axes, not the vector.
- Similarly, we can look at the o_y component of the last term and see that the minus sign needs to be on the second row of R_x, meaning (thank goodness for sanity) the both R_z and R_x right-handed rotations of the axes.

Your Rx and Rz functions are currently defining right handed rotations of a vector, not the axes.

You can fix this by either (all three are equivalent):

- Removing the minus signs on your euler angles: `Rz(O) * Rx(i) * Rz(w)`
- transposing your rotation matrices: `Rz(-O).T * Rx(-i).T * Rz(-w).T`
- moving the `-` sign in the definition of Rx and Rz to the second row sine term, as shown above

Comment: Thanks, that does clarify things a bit -- but unfortunately I still get an unexpected result. I've added more information above that might clarify things.

Comment: Also, sorry for being thick, but you said "It turns out that they are rotations of the axes, not the vector", and I am unclear on the implication. Does that mean that there is an intermediate step, rather than applying the rotation matrix directly to the vector?

Comment: no problem.  Every rotation matrix can be interpreted two ways: it can be thought of as rotating a vector in one direction or as rotating the axes in the opposite direction.  The only question here is which sine term in your rotation matrix definition should have a minus sign in front of it.  I will try to clarify the answer some more

Comment: Aha! Okay, makes perfect sense. But then I would assume that having the axis/vector rotation confused would just result in the rotation in the wrong direction, rather than the somewhat bonkers plots I'm seeing?

Comment: correct.  I suspect that your longitude of the ascending node and argument of periapsis angles are being computed incorrectly.  To get an ellipsoidal path, those two angles should be almost the same throughout the whole orbit. Are they?

Comment: You're right. Something has gone wrong with those. The computation in the linked orbit class is copied from section 4. here: https://downloads.rene-schwarz.com/download/M002-Cartesian_State_Vectors_to_Keplerian_Orbit_Elements.pdf but I will check it again. I'm sure I have implemented something wrong.

Comment: That document says nothing about the computation of those two angles, only that you should rotate by them.  Presumably, you would just need to pick those values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98819/discussion-between-stochastic-and-michael-schuller).

Answer (score 0):

I am going to mark stochastic's answer as right, because a) he deserves the points for being so helpful, and b) his advice was fundamentally correct.

However the source of the weird plot actually ended up being these lines in the linked `Orbit` class:

```
    self.v_position = self.rotate(v_position, self.long_of_asc_node, self.inclination, self.argument_of_periapsis)
    self.v_velocity = self.rotate(v_velocity, self.long_of_asc_node, self.inclination, self.argument_of_periapsis)
```

Notice that the `self.v_position` property is updated before the call to rotate the velocity vector happens; one might also notice, when reading the code, that I in my cleverness decided to make all of the orbital element values methods wrapped in `@property` decorators to make the calculations more clear.

But of course, this also means the methods are called -- and the values recalculated -- every time a property was accessed. So the second call to `self.rotate()` happens with slightly different values of the orbital elements from the first call and, more importantly, with values that don't match up 100% correctly with the "current" position and velocity state vectors!

So after a few days of banging my head against this bug, I figured it out from a bit of yak-shaving I was doing in the form of a refactoring, and now it all works perfectly.